# Why react-snap push fails to Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, react-snap

I went through setup of `react-snap`, but when pushing to `Heroku` it fails.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snap

Do you have any idea why?

```
remote: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
remote: /tmp/build_7dd913c10a184386f4680b1463b79feb/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686378/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[image]

---

I added the buildpacks required:

[image]